# Is there a shorthand way to wrap properties of a component object of a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

See snippet below:

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.bar = new Bar(y);
  }
  get y() {
    return this.bar.y;
  }
  set y(val) {
    this.bar.y = val;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(1, 2);
console.log(foo.x, foo.y);
```

I would love for a shorthand way to map something like (pseudocode)
    Foo.y = this.bar.y

Comment: No, there's not. Of course you could write a helper function to which you just pass `Foo.prototype, "bar", "y"`, but for only a single property there's no benefit in that.

Comment: I don't know about your goal, but did you consider using inheritance instead of composition?

Comment: @Bergi I'd be interested in fleshing out that idea -- I have a use case where this pattern is used many times (wrapping objects from a 3rd party game engine)

Comment: @jonchun what about the decorator pattern, then? You will have to make a wrapper `Foo` that accepts a `Bar` instance and then delegates some calls to it but also has its own.

Comment: Why do you need to wrap this? You're not adding any extra behaviour right now. It might be worth just using the engine primitive until you need to add extra behaviour to it.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm familiar with Python decorators but didn't know they were a thing in JS. This looks very promising and I think is exactly what I want.

Comment: @DanPantry mostly just convenience. I'd like to do something like `this.entity.x` instead of `this.entity.gameobject.body.x`

Comment: @jonchun the [decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is language agnostic and is often used when trying to extend the functionality of foreign objects without modifying them or binding yourself with inheritance.

Comment: @VLAZ -- still experimental in JS, but I think that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @jonchun OK, if you specifically want to *wrap* other objects, then of course inheritance is out of the question. Have a look at my answer for the helper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper method to create the getter/setter pairs programmatically with `Object.defineProperties`:

```
function createAccessors(o, path, properties) {
  for (const p of properties)
    Object.defineProperty(o, p, {
      get() { return path(this)[p]; },
      set(v) { path(this)[p] = v; },
    });
}

class Bar {
  constructor(y, z) {
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.bar = new Bar(y, z);
  }
}
createAccessors(Foo.prototype, foo => foo.bar, ["y", "z"]);

const foo = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
console.log(foo.x, foo.y, foo.z);
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I love what you're doing here, but unfortunately I forgot to mention that I'm using typescript for this particular project and it cries if I try to do this. I'm still marking your answer as correct since it directly achieves what I asked for. (Kudos to @VLAZ as well for the decorator pattern thoughts) I will definitely consider this if I come across a use case like this again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yoo can extend `Bar` class and call the super class constructor with value of `y`.

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor(x, y) {
    super(y);
    this.x = x;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(1, 2);
console.log(foo.x, foo.y);
```

Or alternately you can copy property simple using `Object.assign` method.

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(y) {
    this.y = y;
  }
}
class Bar1 {
  constructor(z) {
    this.z = z;
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    Object.assign(this, new Bar(y), new Bar1(z));
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
console.log(foo.x, foo.y, foo.z);
```

Comment: This pattern breaks if I have another property this.baz = Baz(z); where Baz works exactly like Bar, and I want this.z to really mean this.baz.z

Comment: @jonchun : ya in that cae you may have to use multilevel inheritance

Comment: @jonchun : may be u can use `Object.assign`